# Convexity of the surface $x^2+z^2-y^3(1-y)^3 = 0$

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, surfaces

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider the surface $F$ given by $$F= \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \colon x^2+z^2-y^3(1-y)^3 = 0 \right\}$$ For which points on the surface is $F$ convex?
>
> REMARK: The surface looks like [this one](https://imaginary.org/gallery/herwig-hauser-classic) here:
>
> [image]

I would say that from the graphic it is obvious that $F$ is not convex, because it cannot contain a line segment of two points due to its roundness. But the part of the question "For which points on the surface" confuses me. What is meant by that?

Comment: Where does this question come from? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: I'm guessing it means something like this: If you take the set where the expression is $\le 0$ instead of $=0$, then you can cut off the ends at appropriate places to get a convex set. If so, it would be the same as determining where the curvature is positive.

Comment: +1 for the tasty-looking Zitrus